# Home theater / general audio SE site?

Tags: discussion

I usually ask audio equipment-related questions over at [AudioKarma](http://www.audiokarma.org/). Being a big fan of SE sites I thought I'd see if SE had an equivalent network site. I came across this site, but as it turns out, it doesn't really seem to be appropriate to ask home audio or general audio questions here (right?).

Is there a home theater / general audio SE site? That doesn't seem to be the case but thought I'd ask. It seems conspicuously missing in SE's site list. Would be nice to have something that covers all the topics AudioKarma covers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topic of a home theater related site is one that comes up in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59720/home-theater-audio) from time to time, however the general problem is that of subject matter.  For the most part, Home Theater comes down to product review and recommendation rather than that much in the way of Q/A format content.

We tried some level of handling such questions back with AVP prior to the split, but ran in to problems from low quality of the questions and not really being of interest to those in production since they really are distinct fields.  [Here](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here) is the meta post on Video Production about why Non-Production questions are off topic.  The same reasoning carried over to here.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point; home theater topics in particular seem to have a tendency to degenerate in to back-and-forth opinions and reviews. Maybe best to leave those to all those uncivilized forums (ew).

Comment: Yeah, I've watched at least a couple Area51 attempts at Home Theater/Audiophile fail

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, there was an Audio Production Stack Exchange, which was merged into an Audio/Video Production SE, from which audio questions were split off to be merged with *this* site when it was brought back "into the fold". This is why I have 1000 rep here without being a sound designer.

This site has since been defined to not include audio production, but that should *technically* be within scope of the current [*video* production SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Audio Production is still on topic here.  Extremely basic stuff is currently in debate about being on topic.  Home theater stuff had been off topic on both AVP and SSD prior to the split/merge.  Audio stuff is only on topic on Video Production when associated with video.  A stand alone audio question would be migrated back over here.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] page _really_ needs to be updated to reflect that. Recent meta questions seem to indicate a more strict definition of Sound Design.

Comment: yeah, we have a bit of an identity crisis at the moment that we are trying to resolve.  Btw, if you want to give your input on what you think it should be, you can do so [here](http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com/questions/169/what-is-sound-design).  Traa is working on a proposal for topic text as well and we'll be working through trying to figure out which parts of each should go in to it.  We are trying to make sure we don't leave out anyone that formerly had a home though.

Comment: @AJHenderson Would like to meet you in chat right about now if you're available